# Почему приложения нет в поиске?

Tags: java, android, google-play, playmarket

Месяц назад разместил приложение в Google Play, но его до сих пор нету в поиске. В данный момент пытаюсь набрать аудиторию из знакомых чтобы перевалить за 100 установок, может тогда появится. А вообще не нужно ли было добавлять что-нибудь в код для успешного поиска приложения?
Какие дадите советы по этому поводу?

Comment: Всё зависит от никому (даже гуглу) не известных алгоритмов, в которых могут быть баги. Ваш случай не уникален и, вроде, через неизвестное время всё может само-собой исправиться. Слышал также, что может помочь реклама приложения в маркете. Вроде бы за несколько тысяч рублей, потраченных на рекламу можно подтолкнуть алгоритмы к обращению внимания на приложение.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб А в любом случае появится в поиске?)

Comment: Никаких гарантий нет. Гуглу плевать на независимых разработчиков и вы можете лишь надеяться, что вам повезёт и оно как-то само в итоге заработает(